# Create continuous effect for card game

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I was trying to figure out the code of some cards of the popular game Hearthstone and reproducing it with Python. I said Hearthstone, but this can apply basically to every card game, like Magic the Gathering etc...
Lets say I have a creature on the field:

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self,manacost,atk,health):
        self.manacost = manacost
        self.atk = atk
        self.health = health

creature = Creature(2,3,2)
field = []
field.append(creature)
```

Now, this creature has a continuous effect like "Spells in your hand cost 1 less". That means that WHILE the card is on the field my spells will cost 1 less, and they will return to their original cost as soon the card leaves the field.
Then I wrote:

```
class Spell:
    def __init__(self,manacost):
        self.manacost = manacost

s1 = Spell(1)
s2 = Spell(2)
s3 = Spell(3)

hand = [s1,s2,s3]

while creature in field == True:
    for spell in hand:
        if spell.manacost >=1:
            spell.manacost -= 1
```

At first I expected to end up with all my spells having `manacost` equal to `0`.
Instead nothing happened.
Typing

```
[x.manacost for x in hand]
```

I get `[1,2,3]`, which are the exact same `manacost`s I set for the spells in the beginning. How can I do?

EDITED POST ANSWERS

In the end here is my code fixed (i had to post it here and not in answers cause i didn't have enough characters in the reply slot.

```
class Creature:
    def __init__(self,manacost,atk,health):
        self.manacost = manacost
        self.atk = atk
        self.health = health
    def continuous_effect(self):
        global spellcostdifference
        spellcostdifference += 1
    def continuous_effect_cancel(self):
        global spellcostdifference
        spellcostdifference -= 1

class Spell:
    def __init__(self,manacost):
        self.manacost = manacost
    def current_manacost(self):
        global spellcostdifference
        return self.manacost - spellcostdifference if spellcostdifference <= self.manacost else 0

spellcostdifference = 0
creature = Creature(2,3,2)
s1 = Spell(1)
s2 = Spell(2)
s3 = Spell(3)
hand = [s1,s2,s3]

creature.continuous_effect() ## this means the creature is on the field
creature.continuous_effect_cancel() ## this means the creature left the field or got its effect negated
```

Thanks a lot for your help guys =)

Comment: The for loop without the while statement works - `creature in field == True` must be evaluating as False. Print something just before the for loop - did it print?

Comment: For statements the evaluate to a boolean, you do not need to compare to True, or False.  `while creature in field == True` --> `while creature in field:`.

Comment: The `while creature in field == True:` looks like it could cause an infinite loop. There's nothing in the code within it that changes the contents of `field`, so the condition will either be `True` and stay that way forever, or the entire thing will be skipped if it's `False` initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does look deceivingly similar to English/pseudocode, but in this case, the meanings differ. As you tagged the question, the construct `while <condition>: <looping code>` is a loop, which means that when the program reaches this point, it will keep running the wrapped code as long as the condition is true.

In this case, your code would have been an infinite loop if not for a problem with [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). What you wrote was interpreted as:

```python
while creature in (field == True):
    for spell in hand:
        if spell.manacost >=1:
            spell.manacost -= 1
```

which will never run, instead of

```python
while (creature in field) == True:
    for spell in hand:
        if spell.manacost >=1:
            spell.manacost -= 1
```

or equivalently

```python
while creature in field:
    for spell in hand:
        if spell.manacost >=1:
            spell.manacost -= 1
```

which are both infinite loops that will keep running forever.

---

What you want is instead a *function* that calculates the current mana cost, based on the original mana cost and current modifiers, like Atto suggested.

One way to do it would be as a new method in the `Spell` class, like this:

```python
class Spell:
    def current_manacost(self, field, creature):
        if creature in field:
            return self.manacost - 1
        else:
            return self.manacost

    def __init__(self,manacost):
        self.manacost = manacost

print([x.current_manacost(field, creature) for x in hand])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLasQwDLz7K3SMwQ0kvhV66if0uIRgEpmYuk6wvLD9@lSOm4TdHrY6CD1mhGaW7zTNQa/r4A0RvEc06RrxVQDHiBb63gWX@r4i9FZ9mWCGmZIy6VNNaHyaZMHmyJB6h8Ab7OU9gKm843w/Ltd4Uwohht9feLS/VbVKq1YK69CPPL90pazNsmAYq50imb3p@VjQ@1PMcI0RQ@r3x4oo2G4oONinImePKbhQgOc2R0RehgfpL9AcIPSEzyniieH/cVlQw@0muWqkoPbo2DLSR6fZnsmEzUBqFLWKdCeEWKILqbrc6j82PRoEdo5wy47kO51c1x8)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and accuracy explaining everything. I really appreciate. I was able to fix my code, i edited my original post for characters lack reasons. Again, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a while loop, this will constantly lower all of the mana costs to 0. You probably want a completely different variable holding the buffs/debuffs.

For example:

```
spell_manacost_modifier = 0

class Spell:
    def __init__(self,manacost):
        self.manacost = manacost

def calculate_cost(spell):
    final_cost = spell.manacost + spell_manacost_modifier
    return final_cost if final_cost >=0 else 0

s1 = Spell(1)
s2 = Spell(2)
s3 = Spell(3)

hand = [s1,s2,s3]

# this specific if statement should be run when the turn starts, after of course setting spell_manacost_modifier to 0
if creature in field:
    spell_manacost_modifier -= 1

for spell in hand:
    print(calculate_cost(spell))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fast and helpful response man, it was indeed the right solution, you can check my original post to see how i changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions that evaluate to a boolean do not need to compared to True, or False.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> 1 in a == True
False
```

`a == True` is being evaluated before `1 in a`. Reference [6.16 Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

```
>>> 1 in a
True
>>> a == True
False

>>> (1 in a) == True
True
>>>
```

Change:

```
while creature in field == True
```

to

```
while creature in field:
```

Comment: Yes, but that change will not make the code work. Instead, it will become an infinite loop that does nothing.

Comment: @Hjulle - OP stated `I expected to end up with all my spells having manacost equal to 0`.

Comment: @Hjulle - maybe the example is a simplification and at some point the actual code's execution the creature gets eaten.

Comment: Ok, yes, the loop does set the mana costs equal to 0, but after that, it keeps looping infinitely, so there's no way to verify it.